# How to create condition based query using Eloquent ORM Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Can I use this code with if condition like this?

```
$testq= DB::table('attendances')
    if($flag==1)
    ->where('type', '=', $userinput)
    else
    ->where('type', '=', $newdate)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can. This will work for you:

```
$query = DB::table('attendances');

if($flag == 1) {
  $query->where('type', '=', $userinput)
} else {
  $query->where('type', '=', $newdate)
}

$result = $query->get();
```